# Replicating CRAN valgrind issues

Tags: r, valgrind, rcpp, cran

I am trying to fix some issue with my package `CamelUp` on CRAN. This package uses Rcpp to implement a board game. My recent CRAN submissions have come back with comments and output such as:

```
==32365== 16,591,624 (2,608,512 direct, 13,983,112 indirect) bytes in
20,379 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3,036 of 3,036
==32365==    at 0x4838E86: operator new(unsigned long)
(/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.15.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:344)
==32365==    by 0x184ED3E5: Board::Board(Board const&)
(/tmp/CamelUp.Rcheck/00_pkg_src/CamelUp/src/Board.cpp:67)
...
==32365==    by 0x1853045D: Simulator::simulateDecision(bool, int)
(/tmp/CamelUp.Rcheck/00_pkg_src/CamelUp/src/Simulator.cpp:64)
==32365==    by 0x18536509: Rcpp::CppMethod2<Simulator, Rcpp::Vector<19,
Rcpp::PreserveStorage>, bool, int>::operator()(Simulator*, SEXPREC**)
(R-devel/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/Module_generated_CppMethod.h:195)
==32365==    by 0x18535B32:
Rcpp::class_<Simulator>::invoke_notvoid(SEXPREC*, SEXPREC*, SEXPREC**,
int) (R-devel/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/module/class.h:234)
==32365==    by 0x17B9EBE1: CppMethod__invoke_notvoid(SEXPREC*)
(/tmp/RtmpKDbrDI/R.INSTALL1d1838b282b2/Rcpp/src/module.cpp:220)
```

I'm having trouble replicating these errors and I'm wondering if there is a straightforward way to use valgrind with my package to reproduce these errors. I've tried running locally with valgrind but couldn't get the track origins option to work and make it clear where these errors were in my code. I have also tried using Travis-CI with the following .travis.yml file:

```
language: r
cache: packages
r_check_args: '--use-valgrind'
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - valgrind
r:
  - oldrel
  - release
  - devel
env:
  - VALGRIND_OPTS='--tool=memcheck --memcheck:leak-check=full --track-origins=yes'
```

I'm hoping there is a way to replicate these errors so I can fix them.

Comment: Do you have access to Linux?  If not, can you run a Docker container?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel yes I have docker running, but I am struggling to get valgrind working within docker to check my package. I have found your blog http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2019/08/05/#023_rocker_debug_example and I'm working on getting it running. I am very confused why --use-valgrind in R CMD check doesn't reproduce the CRAN errors without Docker.

Comment: Valgrind can take some getting used to. I often recommend to even compile a three line C program, maybe even with a malloc and no free "just to see" how it reports. For R it is doubly tricky as an interpreter it *will* leave some things behind.  But the docs in a) the Writing R Extensions manual and b) other tutorials like mine should help.

Comment: That blog details how to compile with a newer compiler; it does not show `valgrind` use. I _did_ show how to debug with `valgrind` way-back-when in tutorials, see _e.g_ at the end of this one:  https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/rFinanceHPC.pdf

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you. Those slides were very helpful. I'm now running valgrind in Docker and I'm able to replicate some of the CRAN errors. However, I'm only able to do this by running `R -d "valgrind -tool=memcheck -leak-check=full"
-vanilla < test-board.R` for each file in the tests/testthat directory manually. It seems like ideally I would source testthat.R, but test_check seems to only be useful in R CMD check. Do you know of a succinct way to run all tests from the command line?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/04/05/debugging-with-valgrind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully used Docker to run valgrind for my tests, but I ended up deciding that the best way to integrate this testing was with Travis-CI. My .travis.yml file looks like this:

```
language: r
cache: packages
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - valgrind
r:
  - oldrel
  - release
  - devel

after_success:
  - R -e "install.packages('${PKG_TARBALL}', repos=NULL, type='source')"
  - cd tests
  - R -d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes"  --vanilla < testthat.R
  - cd ..
```

This now runs the tests with valgrind, although I have to manually scroll through to see the results. At some point I will make the build fail if there are memory leaks, but for now this works for me. I was mostly unfamiliar with Docker and valgrind, and didn't realize I need to be in the tests directory to run the tests in `testthat.R`.

Comment: If a package is more complicated, Travis can cause more problems, however, eg timeouts, and environment differences that are themselves hard to pin down via Travis. Glad you got a solution without these issues. IIRC rhub has a valgrind capability.